# struggling with ImageButton animation

Tags: android, animation, swipe, imagebutton, effect

I'm struggling with **Android Animation** and I would like to see ImageButton going out of the screen when swiping left and make them come inside the screen when **swiping** right. 
I think I should use a **translate** effect, but I don't know exactly how to see the button moving on the whole path. 
I want to make the swiping intuitive, so the user should see that Button went out and in which direction.
I tried this one:

```
 final Animation move = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.animator.moveout);
 menubarlayout.startAnimation(shake);
```

**moveout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
   android:duration="500"
   android:fillAfter="true"
   android:fromXDelta="10"
   android:fromYDelta="0"
   android:toXDelta="0%"
   android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

Comment: show us some effort. what have you tried so far?

Comment: show the code implementation how you assigned the animation also

Comment: both xml and code seem fine. where are you having problems?